# SecureAMFChannel with certificat

Tags: apache-flex, https, certificate, remoteobject

Basically, I'm using a remote object that access to a secure EndPoint. This 
EndPoint is located into my server. It means that my channel is a 
SecureAMFChannel. If I accept the certificat by going directly to this URL with 
my browser, then I'm able to run my flex application and to exchange some data.

However, if I'dont go to this url to accept the server's certificat, and launch 
my Flex application, the remoteObject is not able to accept the certificat. And 
of course, any information can be exchanged.

My problem is, how to accept automatically a certificat in a Flex application. 
Do I need to configure something to accept it? Maybe my manipulation is not 
correct.

My certificat is self-signed, do you think that this problem could be solved by buying a Certificat signed by a CA?

Could you tell how to solve this?

Thank you very much,

Bat

Answer (score 1):

You can't accept a self-signed certificate in Flex. The Flash Player trusts only those CAs that are trusted by the browser.

So, either add your own CA which you used to sign your certificate to the trusted CAs of your browser or buy a certificate from a well known CA. I'd strongly advise you to do the latter since using self-signed certificates is more or less as insecure as using no SSL/TLS at all.